# Angularjs: Calling a method from service inside my filter

Tags: angularjs

Inside my service.js, I included a filter that needs to call a function. However, the said function is declared just below my filter declaration (still inside my service.js). Below is a snippet of my filter:

```
angular
.module('app.inquiry')
.factory('InquiryService', InquiryService)
.filter("getCode", function(){
   return function(item) {
      searchProduct(item.name).then(function(result) {
        item.reference.local = result;
        return item.reference.local;
      })
   }
});
```

Inside my `function InquiryService` is another function named `searchProduct`, the function I used inside my filter. However, this doesnt work. Is it possible to call a method from my service inside a filter? If so, how can I reference the said method to be called? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a method from my service inside a filter?

Yes, it's. You should *inject* your `factory` inside your filter, as below:

```
.filter("getCode", function(InquiryService) {
```

Then, you can call the method from your `factory` like this:

```
.filter("getCode", function(InquiryService) {
    return function(item) {
      InquiryService.searchProduct(item.name).then(function(result) {
        item.reference.local = result;
        return item.reference.local;
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: EDIT: What I actually included is 

`.filter("getCode", ['InquiryService', function(InquiryService) {`

and it works fine now.